# React how to use setInterval with useEfecct and axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, setinterval

Where I've to use setInterval to fetch every second?
When i try it i get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getHistory = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/payment', {
        headers: { Authorization: token },
      });
      setHistory(res.data);
    };
    getHistory();
  }, [token, delivered]);
```

Comment: Log that exception with .catch on axios. Like axios.get().catch(e => console.log(e)) , mostly it looks like your api calls are failing or your backend is not sending back correct response. But again that’s my hunch, you can log the error to figure the exact reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`swr`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval) for this and benefit from not only built-in revalidation on interval, but also caching and deduplication.

```
import useSWR from 'swr'

// You can use axios if you want
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())

const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/payment', fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 })

if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
return <div>Look at all this data: {data.someProperty}</div>
```